# Google URL Shortener API 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-url-shortener

I've been exploring google APIs lately and have been playing around with their URL shortening API. I am authenticating using oAuth and have that part down pat. I have managed to successfully use the get and list functions of the API but am having problems making the insert function work.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const urlshortener = google.urlshortener({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: auth
});

async function insert(lengthened) {
    return await urlshortener.url.insert({
        requestBody: {
            longUrl: lengthened
        },
        fields: 'id'
    });
}
```

Where in this case auth is simply an already authenticated google oauth client that gets passed in from another file.

Curiously, when I try to call this function I get the following error:

```
[ { domain: 'global', reason: 'forbidden', message: 'Forbidden' } ]
```

I have scanned through the rest of the response and have not found any additional info. This is strange to me because the other two functions work, I am using oAuth so there should be no problems with API key limiting, and both of the other two API methods work.

My oAuth authentication scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener
```

Comment: Starting March 30, 2018, Google will be turning down support for goo.gl URL shortener. They removed the support in the library as well (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/pull/1284).

Comment: Thank you! This explains everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on the original question. Google is discontinuing support for their URL shortener. This is why retrieving data using this library is possible while creating a new shortened URL is not.